# Symfony 6 : how to import bundle translations?

Tags: php, symfony, translation, symfony6

I'm using Symfony 6 and don't understand how I should enable translation for dependency messages.
For example: I just installed SymfonyCasts/verify-email-bundle which provides translations in its directory (src/Resources/translations)

To enable them, I have:

- installed the translation bundle with: `composer require symfony/translation`
- set the `default_locale` to `fr` in my config/packages/translation.yaml
- cleared the cache with `bin/console cache:clear`
- also tried to manually clear translation cache as stated in other related posts : `rm -rf var/log/translations`

Then, all messages that should be handled by the provided translations are still in English.

I have also tried to force translation by calling myself the `$translator->trans()` method on the string returned by the bundle. The profiler then says the translation is missing and fallbacks to `en` as configured.

I have tried to copy the bundle VerifyEmailBundle.fr.xlf file into my own /translations directory but got the same error. `bin/console debug:translation fr` shows me the needed translations but all are marked as `unused`.

I encounter the same issue with multiple bundles and don't see anything in the offical documentation about this.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

To set default language you must set #config/packages/translation.yaml like this:

```
framework:
    default_locale: fr
    translator:
        default_path: '%kernel.project_dir%/translations'
        fallbacks:
            - fr
```

and you can add translations at #translations/messages.fr.yml

```
Hello: 'Bonjour'
This friendly message is coming from: 'Ce message amical vient de'
Welcome to my new App: 'Bienvenue sur ma nouvelle application'
user:
  profile:
    admin: 'administrateur'
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I understand what you are proposing but I don't want to go there.
My app is 100% stateless and I don't want to start a session for each user. Also, I don't get why I should force locale for each user like this whereas there is a `default_locale` specifically for this purpose.
There has to be a way to set a default locale once and for all, right?

Comment: ok, I undestand you. Look my solution for you updated

Comment: No that's not what I'm asking: I'm looking for a way to enable translations that are already provided by bundles. These translations are seen by symfony but marked "unused" and never triggered when needed.
Besides, I even tried your way by copying bundle translations into my own /translations directory but got nothing bett

Comment: I think you need to make a fresh project and test this, because this is the offical solution and this must work.

Comment: This must but this doesn't. That's exactly what I'm saying here: from a fresh project, with only the steps I provided I can't bring external translations to work